# Как задеплоить Maven проект Tomcatом?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, развертывание

При сборке проекта maven получаю war файл в папке `target`. При попытке его задеплоить через конфигурацию Tomcat в idea происходит следующее: показывается стандартная страница Tomcat

> If you're seeing this, you've successfully installed Tomcat. Congratulations!

По `actions` не переходит. `index.html` выходит тоже не видит. Как исправить?
porm file:

```
 <artifactId>SimpleInternetShop</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <spring.version>4.1.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <cglib.version>3.2.0</cglib.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring core & mvc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- CGLib for @Configuration -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
        <version>${cglib.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Servlet Spec -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>



<build>
    <finalName>Simple_internet_shop</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <webXml>web\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: помогите люди!!

Comment: HELP ME!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Если томкат установлен, то либо настраиваешь в среде (run\debug conf -> Tomcat Server -> Deployment -> Add your war exploded ), либо кладешь в Tomcat -> webapps свой варник и стартуешь Tomcat (после этого локалност:8080/YourWarName)

Comment: пробовал. В первом варианте выдает стартовую страницу томката, а при втором просто не видит ссылки на мой war

Comment: выложи тогда pom file

Comment: выложил. Дело в том, что с другим проектом у меня было тоже самое, хотя он успешно запускался на компьютере моего друга.